# How can I find the host OS from a docker container?

Tags: docker

I am running my code in a docker container, and I need to know whether the host is macOS, windows or linux. How do I do that? Any undocumented hack will do, I just need to log this info for troubleshooting.

Comment: I don't think there's a documented way, but there is an OS-specific way that DNS lookups for `host.docker.internal` and `docker.for.mac.localhost` are handled. Specifically, on Docker Desktop for Mac, both of those exist; on Docker Desktop for Windows, only the first one exists, and on Docker Engine for Linux, neither exist.

Answer (score 0):

From what I read, this is not intended to work. You can always pass environment variables when starting your container, and that probably might be your best bet here:

For [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/):

```
web:
  environment:
    - HOST_OS=linux
```

For [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file):

```
docker run --env HOST_OS=linux
```

Where the value of HOST_OS can either be hard coded or another environment variable from the host's OS.

Since you wrote that is is for troubleshooting only, this should be sufficient, however, if you plan to handle different operating systems differently within your container, you may consider using a language with a runtime environment (C#, Java, ...).